# For ALL queries in SQL , Table division

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema with three tables:

> **Project** (*project_id*,proj_name,chief_arch)
>   **Employee** (*emp_id*,emp_name)
>   **Assigned-to** (*project_id,emp_id*)

I have created all tables with data on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f21e
You can view the all data (select * ...) on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f21e/1
*Please first view the tables and data on SQLFIDDLE.*

I have an existing query to get employee names who work on *at least one project* where employee 107 also worked:

```
select EMP_NAME from employee natural join `assigned-to`
WHERE EMP_ID<>'107' AND 
PROJECT_ID IN(
  SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM `assigned-to`
  WHERE EMP_ID='107'
  )
GROUP BY EMP_NAME;
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f21e/5)**

But now I need to solve a slightly different problem. I need the employee names who on work on **ALL** projects that employee 107 works on.

How can I write a query for this problem?

Comment: What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: I have tried putting ALL after IN clause @bohemian

Comment: I want all employee names who works on all projects in which employee with employeeID 107 works on @Md.SumanKabir

Comment: Just a comment becaues it seems like this is already answered, but I can offer some perspective on solving this in the future. Think of it as first looking at the projects emp#107 worked, and looking for employees who do **NOT** work on at least one of those projects. You already know how to do that part. Once you have that list, you can **invert it** from your full set of employees... any employee not in the list worked all of the projects that 107 did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EMP_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE NATURAL JOIN `ASSIGNED-TO`
WHERE EMP_ID<>'107' AND 
PROJECT_ID IN (
  SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM `ASSIGNED-TO`
  WHERE EMP_ID='107'
)
GROUP BY EMP_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*)=(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `ASSIGNED-TO`
  WHERE EMP_ID='107'
);
```

See it run on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f21e/30).

Comment: thanks i have not imagine that it can be solved so easily like this ... thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by counting the projects other employees in common with the employee and then selecting only those where the count exactly matches the original employees count.

```
SELECT EMP_ID FROM `ASSIGNED-TO` WHERE PROJECT_ID IN 
  (SELECT PROJECT_ID FROM `ASSIGNED-TO` WHERE EMP_ID = '107')
AND EMP_ID <> '107'
GROUP BY EMP_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ASSIGNED-TO` WHERE EMP_ID = '107')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too.  I want to validate if the project id in assigned-to is found in project table.

```
select e.emp_name 
from  employee e
natural join `assigned-to` a
where emp_id <> 107  
and  a.project_id in (
     select project_id 
     from (
       select emp_id, project_id
         from employee natural join `assigned-to` natural join project
         where emp_id = 107  ) t 
          )
group by e.emp_id
having count(project_id) = (select count(project_id) from `assigned-to` where emp_id = 107)
```